# Can Tentacle of the Deeps be cast on the surface of water?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock

The Warlock subclass The Fathomless has an ability called Tentacle of the Deeps that reads:

> You can magically summon a spectral tentacle that strikes at your
> foes. As a bonus action, you create a 10-foot-long tentacle at a point
> you can see within 60 feet of you. The tentacle lasts for 1 minute or
> until you use this feature to create another tentacle. When you create
> the tentacle, you can make a melee spell attack against one creature
> within 10 feet of it. On a hit, the target takes 1d8 cold damage, and
> its speed is reduced by 10 feet until the start of your next turn.
> When you reach 10th level in this class, the damage increases to 2d8.
> As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the tentacle up to 30
> feet and repeat the attack. You can summon the tentacle a number of
> times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended
> uses when you finish a long rest.

Would that be able to stand on the surface of water?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.StackExchange! Be sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have questions. Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 11):

### On the surface, under the surface, over the surface

The limit of the spell is “a point you can see” - if you can see it, you can target it.

Oh, and a clear path to the target per the general rule for targeting.

Comment: notably, you could also summon the tentacle in midair - might be worth clarifying that. Lore-wise, the tentacle could be coming from some kind of rift, so this would make sense.